# Insert image into cassandra blob using Java

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.1, cassandra-jdbc

I wish to insert image as bytebuffer into cassandra table.

Table is:
Employees(Name text,Image blob)

I had stored image into variable bb in form of bytebuffer using Java.
How to insert data from this bytebuffer bb into cassandra table?
Can anyone please help?

Comment: Be aware of the maximum mutation size. And storing blobs larger than 1MB (IIRC) is not recommended.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the ByteBuffer directly with the Java driver.

See the example on http://ac31004.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/saving-image-in-cassandra-blob-field.html:

```
ByteBuffer buffer =ByteBuffer.wrap(b);

....
// image is of type blob
PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare("insert into Messages (image, user, interaction_time,imagelength) values(?,?,?,?)");
BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(ps);

session.execute(boundStatement.bind(buffer, "Andy", convertor.getTimeUUID(),length));
```

See they directly bind the ByteBuffer to the blob-type parameter in the prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks Alec! I tried above link.I am working on Linux server which is at remote location. I am getting following error:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed.